# An Application: The Stone-Cech Compactification

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

If $X$ is completely regular, show that $X$ is open in $βΧ$ if and only if $X$ is locally 
compact.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If $X$ is open in $\beta X$, use complete regularity and the fact that $\beta X\setminus X$ is closed to show that $X$ is locally compact. If $X$ is locally compact, use the fact that every compact set in $X$ is closed in $\beta X$ (why?) to show that every point of $X$ has an open nbhd whose closure in $\beta X$ is contained in $X$, and conclude from this that $X$ is open in $\beta X$.